# Second order differential equation with boundary conditions solving repeatedly

Tags: recursion, differential-equations

I want to solve a second order differential equation in the interval[-1:1], which does not have a analytic solution,
\begin{eqnarray}
y''(x) &=& k \phi^2(x)y(x) \\
\phi(x) &=& \frac{1}{2}\left(1-\sin\left[ \frac{\pi}{2}x\right] \right)\\
y'[1] &=& 1 \\
y[1] &=& 1
\end{eqnarray}

It is possible to get numerical solution of the equation using NDSolve. But
I want to approach the solution iteratively starting with a Initial guess function for example, $y_0(x) = \frac{1}{2}(1+x)$ with appropriate boundary conditions,
\begin{eqnarray}
y_{n+1}''(x) &=& k\phi^2(x)y_n(x) 
\end{eqnarray}

To do this I have following code,

```
ClearAll;
k = 3955/100;
W = 1
phi[x_] := (1/2)*(1 - Sin[(Pi/2)*x/W])
vE[x_] := Piecewise[{{0, -W <= x < 0}, {x/W, 0 <= x <= W}}];
pcw[x_] := (W + x)/(2*W);
so = NDSolve[{u''[x] == k*phi[x]*phi[x]*u[x], u[-W] == 0, u[W] == 1}, 
  u, {x, -W, W}, WorkingPrecision -> 22, InterpolationOrder -> All]
dd[x_] = Q[x] /. 
   First@DSolve[{Q''[x] == k*phi[x]*phi[x]*pcw[x], Q[W] == 1, 
      Q'[W] == 1}, Q, x];
Plot[Evaluate[{dd[t], u[t] /. so, vE[t], pcw[t]}], {t, -W, W}]
dd[x_] = Q[x] /. 
   First@DSolve[{Q''[x] == k*phi[x]*phi[x]*dd[x], Q[W] == 1, 
      Q'[W] == 1}, Q, x];
Plot[Evaluate[{dd[t], u[t] /. so, vE[t], pcw[t]}], {t, -W, W}]
dd[x_] = Q[x] /. 
   First@DSolve[{Q''[x] == k*phi[x]*phi[x]*dd[x], Q[W] == 1, 
      Q'[W] == 1}, Q, x];
Plot[Evaluate[{dd[t], u[t] /. so, vE[t], pcw[t]}], {t, -W, W}]
dd[x_] = Q[x] /. 
   First@DSolve[{Q''[x] == k*phi[x]*phi[x]*dd[x], Q[W] == 1, 
      Q'[W] == 1}, Q, x];
Plot[Evaluate[{dd[t], u[t] /. so, vE[t], pcw[t]}], {t, -W, W}]
```

Which is certainly not elegant way getting things done and also it is taking too long to run than I was expecting. How can I use recursion in this case?

The numeric solution is:

```
Plot[u[x] /. so, {x, -W, W}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: 1) `ClearAll;` accomplishes nothing; maybe you want `Clear["Global`*"]`. 2) Each of your definitions of `pcw` overrides the previous one, so that only the last definition `pcw[x_] := (W + x)/(2*W)` remains in effect at the end. Did you intend that?

Comment: Thank you m_goldberg for the comments..! I will use ClearAll properly now. for the pcw function any definition is good enough.

Comment: If you simply want to make the code elegant, have a look at `Do`, `While`, `Nest`, `NestWhile` etc. Nevertheless, I'm afraid it's hard to speed up the code if you want `dd[x]` to be analytic. BTW, shouldn't the `phi[x] phi[t]` be `phi[x]^2`?

Comment: @xzczd, thanks for pointing out that. phi[x]*phi[t] should be phi[x]^2

Comment: I guess you want an iteration method as in the proof of e.g. Picard's theorem rather thant recurssion. Unfortunately I have no time for answering any questions.

Answer (score 3):

The following is perhaps elegant but not that fast. The main problem is that your ODE is increasing in complexity at each iteration. Applying `N[...]` at each step helps with that but sooner or later (fatally) you'll lose precision and the thing will stop converging to the desired solution.

```
k = 3955/100;
w = 1;
phi[x_] := (1/2) (1 - Sin[Pi/2 x/w])
pcw[x_] := (w + x)/(2 w);
t[f_]:= (q@x/.First[DSolve[{q''@x== k phi@x^2 f, q@w== 1, q'@w== 1}, q, x]]//Simplify) 

nl = NestList[ t[#] &, t[pcw@x], 5];
(* The numeric solution*)
nds = NDSolveValue[{y''[x] == k phi[x]^2 y[x], y'[1] == 1, y[1] == 1},y, {x, -1, 1}]

Show[Plot[nds[x], {x, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}], 
     Plot[nl, {x, -w, w}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

here you can see the increasing complexity

```
LeafCount /@ nl
(* {88, 312, 797, 1659, 3011, 4965} *)
```